# cellular homology/triangulations of suspensions, mapping cones and cylinders

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, book-recommendation

The notion of mapping cone and cylinder for chain complexes is typically motivated by the corresponding notions in topology. For example, take the mapping cone $C_f$ of some map $f\colon X \to Y$. Using Mayer-Vietoris, I think it's straightforward to prove that this gives rise to a long exact sequence in homology. But why does the chain complex of Cf have the form described, for example, here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra)

I imagine with singular homology it's impossible to see this, so here's my question.

> If X and Y are simplicial complexes and f is a simplicial map, where can I find the triangulation of $C_f$ giving rise to that chain complex?

Same question for suspension and mapping cylinder.

> Similarly, if X and Y are cell complexes, is there a cell structure on $C_f$ giving rise to the correct chain complex (via cellular homology)?

Again, same question for suspension and mapping cylinder.

Comment: The standard triangulation on $Y$ and the cone triangulation on $CX$. (Take the cone on every simplex.) Because it's attached by a simplicial map on a subcomplex, this gives a well-defined simplicial complex structure on $C_f$.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks for the explanation. do you have a reference?

Comment: This is true both for simplicial maps between simplicial complexes and for cellular maps between CW-complexes. If $f_\bullet\colon C (X) \to C (Y)$ is the induced morphism of chain complexes, then $C (f_\bullet) = C_\bullet (C_f, pt)$ and $Cyl (f_\bullet) = C_\bullet (Cyl (f))$, via the standard simplicial / CW- structure on the mapping cone/cylinder. Weibel mentions this on p. 19 of his book, and this should be easy to check.